# Android: how to scan for nearby carriers antennas and connect

Tags: android, sim-card, carrier

My question is simple. I would like to know if it is possible to scan for nearby carriers antenna like you can do in your SIM card Android settings.

I would also like to be able to connect / register to a targeted antenna.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You can not just simply scan for antenna. Every antenna has a device behind e.g. a simple radio or modern ones like Bluetooth.
So the modulated radio waves are only transmitted by antenna but the communication protocol is implemented in the broadcasting device which means you have to know what protocol you are scanning for.
For Bluetooth devices there is a Bluetooth-Framework in Android. You can implement a method for scanning BLE devices.
But general keep in mind that antennas are only the transmitter hardware. The modulated radiowaves can have serveral protocols.

Okay now i got it:
Look at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

the method is called `getNetworkOperatorName()`.

Comment: OK ... I get what you say, but I think I was not clear... All I am asking is to ask for Android to tell me what Operator / Carrier (Vodafone, Verizon, Orange, T-Mobile, etc...) are in range, so that I can connect / register my SIM card to it. So far I am able to use `getAllCellInfo` from the **TelephonyManager** class but there is no way to register to one of them ... can you help ? Thanks !

Comment: I am sorry but this does not help. In my comment I explained that I may have found the method that allow me to get the carriers that are in range. But I am also trying to find a way to connect / register to one of this carrier and I don't see how `getNetworkOperatorName()` can help in that matter.